# ClassNotFoundException on hibernate upgrade

Tags: java, hibernate

Im migrating from hibernate 3 to hibernate 4. I am facing the below given issue.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.restor.application.dp.dao.core.db.HibernateListener
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.razorsight.application.dp.dao.core.db.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:49)
at com.razorsight.application.dp.dao.core.db.HibernateListener.contextInitialized(HibernateListener.java:20)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager
at com.razorsight.application.dp.dao.core.db.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:40)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
... 15 more
```

I am not able to solve it in any means. I copied the jars into project and referred them in Build path. Also, changed their references in the ANT Build XMLs

The referred class is present in the build path, and present in the war->WEB-INF-> lib. Still I am getting this issue on server startup.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: have you imported the hibernate jar?

Comment: @greenhorn yes. The jars are in place.! I mean, the jars were copied and referred in the class path

Comment: @greenhorn Seriously,?? You downvoted this question?

Comment: As per findjar the class 'ReflectionManager' is not included in Hibernate 4: http://www.findjar.com/class/org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager.html. Perhaps Hibernate 3 JARs are still in classpath?

Comment: @PavanKumar i haven't and why should i?

Comment: @home Its there in hibernate 4, I can see it when i do Ctrl+Shift+T in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is not duplicate of "`org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager`" in your classpath.

If you are using Maven, then this will help you [maven-duplicate-finder-plugin](https://github.com/ning/maven-duplicate-finder-plugin).

Comment: Im not using Maven, Unfortunately.!! Using Ant.! Any way to resolve this?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, try ctrl-shift-T and search for ReflectionManager. May be it will reveal.

Comment: Can you see multiple instances of ReflectionManager?

Comment: Nope. Only one. and that too from the annotations jara which i have placed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82470/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-and-garry).